# Manually adding property removes records in django query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am writing a Django application where I have model like this:

```
ModelA(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

When querying I am adding, `ModelB` records as a property on ModelA records to use for rendering in template.

```
a_records = ModelA.objects.filter()
for a_record in a_records:
    b_records = ModelB.objects.filter(a=a_record)
    a_record.b_records = b_records
```

But doing this is removing a lot of records from `a_records` so I don't see all of the ModelA records when I render it in a `{% for a in a_records %} {{ a.text }} {% endfor %}` in template.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the related `ModelB` objects manually. If you need to access the *related* `ModelB` objects, you can use:

```
{% for a in a_records %}
    <b>{{ a.text }}</b>
    {% for b in a.modelb_set.all %}
        {{ b.text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

So if you define a `ForeignKey` from model `B` to model `A`, you can access a manager named `.b_set` to access related objects. You can specify a different name with the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

In order to prevent an *N+1* problem, you can use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all the objects in bulk:

```
a_records = ModelA.objects.prefetch_related('b_set')
```